# Calling external json file to radio buttons with php

Tags: php, json

So im trying to make a quiz using an external json file as my data and I want to put each of my choices from my json file and out put them onto my html as radio buttons with php. However, Nothing is coming up. Any advise/solution?

Php code

```
<?php
$json_var = file_get_contents("template.json");
$json_var = json_decode($json_var, true);
foreach($json_var as $value)
{
if($value["name"]=="counting animals"){

  printf('<img src="'.$value["data"].'" />');

  foreach($value["choices"] as $val){
  printf("<form id=\"form1\">");
  printf("  <form name=\"image-pick\" value=\".$val[0].\" type=\"radio\" id=\"one\" >" );
  printf("  <label></label>");
  printf("</form>");
}




}
}

?>
```

Json code

```
[
 {
   "name": "counting animals",
   "template": "counting",
   "data": "Images/5cats.jpg",
   "choices": [
     2,
     5,
     6,
     8
   ],
   "correctAnswer": 1
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `<form>` for each iteration and adding the `type="radio"` to a form tag. You should create the form tag outside of the foreach loop.

I think you are looking for the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) element like  `<input type="radio">` and you should make sure that you don't duplicate the id's in the loop.

That could be done by using for example `id=\"one-$val\"`

```
foreach ($json_var as $value) {
    if ($value["name"] === "counting animals") {
        printf('<img src="' . $value["data"] . '" />');
        printf("<form id=\"form1\">");
        foreach ($value["choices"] as $val) {
            printf("<input name=\"image-pick\" value=$val type=\"radio\" id=\"one-$val\" >" );
            printf("<label></label>");
        }
        printf("</form>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however only the image is coming up and not the radio buttons or the choices

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the data? Can you look at this link? https://3v4l.org/2cCUf

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code and again only the image has loaded up and not the choices

Comment: What do you see when you do right click in the browser and view page source? Just to see if the form and the inputs are there.

Comment: I can see the values being outputted from the json file. 
  <img src="Images/5cats.jpg" /><form id="form1">  <input name="image-pick" value=2 type="radio" id="one" >  <label></label></form><form id="form1">  <input name="image-pick" value=5 type="radio" id="one" >  <label></label></form><form id="form1">  <input name="image-pick" value=6 type="radio" id="one" >  <label></label></form><form id="form1">  <input name="image-pick" value=8 type="radio" id="one" >  <label></label></form>

Comment: But that is not the output from my code. On this page https://3v4l.org/2cCUf you can see what the output should look like. Are you sure you are running the new code? You should have only 1 form tag and no duplicate id's.

Comment: sorry, there was a little mistake. It's now only has 1 tag and no duplicate ids

Comment: unfortunately no, however it is now printing the choices when I put $val within the label, but I still cannot see the radio buttons

Comment: Can you show the page source again? There is no css hiding them?

Comment: I apologise, my css file were hiding the buttons. Its working fine now. thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach($json_var as $value)
{
if($value["name"]=="counting animals"){

  printf('<img src="'.$value["data"].'" />');

  foreach($value["choices"] as $val){
  printf("<form id=\"form1\">");
  printf("  <input name=\"image-pick\" value=$val type=\"radio\" id=\"one\" >" );
  printf("  <label></label>");
  printf("</form>");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. only the image is coming up

Comment: Please,confirm if $value["choices"] is existing.